# Best practice to display nested lists on android

Tags: android

I would like to display a tree without using the tree component, since I don't know how many levels there will be.
I though about a list, that opens another list on item click, and so on...

- Is it correct to open a new activity for each level?
- Will it not overcharge the system?
- Or is it preferable to have only one list that I clear and refill with children?
- How the standard back button will behave on both case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have open a new activity for each level. Unless your tree is extremely deep, it will save you time handling back's button correct behavior by hand if you do it with only one activity.

Comment: opening about 10 activities will not overcharge the system ?

Comment: I use multiple activity, and it's working, thanks for the tips.